# Continuous output instead of classification

Tags: r, regression, classification, dataset, rpart

I was trying to do some classification problem where target variable should be one of 4 classes. I tried `rpart` and `ranger` packages to do this.

```
rf.model <- rpart(Target ~ .-Id, data=train, method="class") 
pred <- predict(rf.model, train) 
View(pred)
```

`pred` looks like this:

[image]

While Target Output should be classified like this:

Target : 
[image]

I had this same problem before with other datasets. Now again I am facing this problem.

What is my mistake and how can I correct it?

Comment: I don't see why this is a problem... Just choose the most likely class as your prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`predict` is a function that does different things depending on what type of object you put into it. Machine learning packages generally put `predict` in their documentation and how to operate it with objects generated by their package. Here is the link for [`rpart`.](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/predict.rpart.html)

The `type` argument is what you are looking for:

```
pred <- predict(rf.model, train, type="class")
```

[For the `ranger` package, `type` depends on what machine learning algorithm you are using.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ranger/versions/0.7.0/topics/predict.ranger)